# Unable to initialize memory with z690 motherboards. Unable to boot to bios, stuck at Q-Code 11

Tags: memory, motherboard, intel

#### I have 2 brand new `Z690` motherboards.

1. The first is an `ASUS Z690 ROG Apex`.
2. The other is an MSI Z690 Force.

---

### My Issue

I've installed the CPU in the socket, a single stick of RAM in the dim closest to the CPU, and connected the power, and the power button. The motherboard turns on,but I am never able to get past Qcode 11. It just sits their. It's the same on both boards, and both boards take the same memory as suggest by crucial. Before I go buy another CPU, I was hoping that someone here might know more about the issue. If there is any additional information you need please let me know in the comments.

- The CPU is a 12th gen 12900K
- The memory I'm trying to initialize with the system is 2x 16GB DDR5 5600mhz 1.1v Crucial Pro *(NOTE: I've tried one and two sticks, and different DIMMs)*

Comment: Appears to be CPU problem, "Pre-memory CPU initialization is started".

Comment: Ahhh.... Fudge is not the word I want to write. Dang it, okay have to buy another cpu. That makes sense. I used a 1.4v stick of DDR5 (the wrong voltage) to see if something happened that didn't happen when I used to correct one (1.1v), and it got stuck at 55, but when I used the right one it moved to pre memory CPU Initialization.

Comment: I'll buy another CPU, if it works I'll update this question so other people in the future will know what to do. Hopefully it works.

Comment: Yeah, don't take my work for it but this is what some ASUS Q code decoder tells me. This, https://www.asusqcodes.com/. I'd check for bent pins and that as well.